# Android - Google autofill not showing update password on change password screen (password fields only)

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager

We've an app with login/signup views.
When a user creates a new account or login the Android autofill framework asks to save the username and password.

Now once the user logs-in -  We've a password fields screen where user can change password by entering current and new password.
But after changing password, it's not asking for update password. Is there any way where force Android autofill framework to update the password?

Comment: I've got the same issue, can't find a working solution :(